# Android Studio - How do I store user ID safely in SharedPreferences for user session?

Tags: android

I'm still learning Android, including its concepts. Currently I'm creating a login system. When someone enter correct **username** and **password**, the application will store user's ID in the **SharedPreferences**.

What I don't want is, someone tries to edit the "currentUserID" session with any user ID so he can **instantly** logged in. In PHP, I can store user ID inside $_SESSION and I think it's safe which no one can see inside and no one can edit it.

So how about the security of SharedPreferences? I've already googled and found that anything with root privileges are able to access it.

Sorry if there's anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Enzokie is it like this: when someone do login, generate a random token, store both inside user's device and server. Then check if token on device is same with token on server?

Answer (score 1):

You can take look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager which will help you.